# Looping until any of the server on different port gives accurate respond in ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, exception

I have 3 servers running beside my app and I am sending RESTful request to them, but I want to have a loop that tries one of these three until it gets accurate response. In my execution when it gets Bad Respond from first server program raises "BadRespondError" and I cannot rescue it in my codes because execution goes to rescue.rb in "actionpack" gem. How could I solve that problem? Can I solve it without working on Execeptions and Errors just with a simple loop or if it is not possible, how could I rescue BadRespondError in my code other than rescue.rb

Here are my code
Requesting
....

```
@response = carrot.dcs_request(uri, {
       "dcs.source" => "etools",
       "query" => @query,
       "dcs.output.format" => "JSON",
       "dcs.clusters.only" => "false"
      })
@json = @response
@response = JSON.parse(@response)
```

....

Request function

```
def dcs_request(uri, data)

    boundary = Array::new(16) { "%2.2d" % rand(99) }.join()
    extheader = {
      "content-type" => "multipart/form-data; boundary=___#{ boundary }___"
    }
    client = HTTPClient.new
    response = client.post_content(uri, data, extheader)
  end
```

So think like uri as an array and I want to loop on it until I get accurate response from one of them.

Comment: I assume the BadResponseError happens in the post_content.  What does post_content do when there is a bad response?  Does it raise BadResponseError?  If so, just rescue it, as Pasted suggested.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a begin..rescue clause with a specific error (BadResponseError)
Somethng like,

```
 begin

 rescue Net::IMAP::BadResponseError, Net::IMAP::NoResponseError => e

 end
```

Shouldn't the rescue clause in the app code be run before Rails raise the error to ActionPack's error handling? (maybe I don't understand the question correctly)

[Begin, Rescue and Ensure in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191632/begin-rescue-and-ensure-in-ruby)

Comment: but when the exception occurred, it goes to rescue.rb in any way without going on my rescue statement.