# Ruby Exceptions and when they stop things

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, exception

I am having trouble understanding ruby exceptions and what happens after an exception occurs.

When an exception happens, and I rescue it, do the commands after the exception still get executed, or does it skip them and jump to the rescue? If I want it to do the stuff after the exception what can I do? Thanks!

In the following example:

```
begin
  var = "string"
  var.do_someting to raise exception
  var.do_something_else
  var.do_something_else_again
rescue => e
  puts "error was #{e}"
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It halts and jumps straight to `rescue`. If there's stuff that **must run no matter what**, `ensure` is probably what you want.

[Begin, Rescue and Ensure in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191632/begin-rescue-and-ensure-in-ruby)

http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_exceptions.html

Comment: Thanks! so if I have multiple things to do after the exception will ensure do both of them? i.e. if the first thing ensure tries to do raises another exception will it break or do the next one as well?

Comment: It will break. But nothing prevents you from surrounding the second thing with a nested begin/rescue/ensure section. But if you're doing that very often, it might indicate an overall design problem.