# Ruby rescue syntax error

Tags: ruby, api, syntax-error, rescue

I have the following line of code that is giving me an error:

```
rescue Timeout::Error => e
    logs.puts("Rescued a timeout error...#{e}")
    email_ids_all.each do |email_delete|

      call= "/api/v2/emails/#{email_delete}/"
      uri= HTTParty.delete("https://www.surveys.com#{call}",
          :basic_auth => auth,
          :headers => { 'ContentType' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Content-Length' => "0" }
      )
      puts "Deleted email #{email_delete}".green
      log.puts("Deleted email #{email_delete}")
    end
    abort #abort entire script after deleting emails
  end
```

The error I am receiving is this:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_rescue, expecting $end
  rescue Timeout::Error => e
        ^
```

Essentially I am just trying to run an API delete call if the script times out. It doesn't seem to matter what I put in the block for `rescue` though, I receive the same error. What's wrong with my syntax on the `rescue` method?

Comment: Apparently you don't have `begin` in proper place. I can't say exactly unless you paste all your code.

Comment: Perhaps the answer is that I don't have `begin` at all. This is the entire code...

Comment: I added begin and the script works fine- Not sure why the downvotes, but thanks for the help. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 20):

The format for using `rescue` is as follows:

```
begin
  # Code you want to run that might raise exceptions
rescue YourExceptionClass => e
  # Code that runs in the case of YourExceptionClass
rescue ADifferentError => e
  # Code that runs in the case of ADifferentError
else
  # Code that runs if there was no error
ensure
  # Code that always runs at the end regardless of whether or not there was an error
end
```

Here is a question with lots more information: [Begin, Rescue and Ensure in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191632/begin-rescue-and-ensure-in-ruby).

Comment: Makes perfect sense- Thanks for the explanation, I was simply missing the `begin` piece.

Comment: @LeviStanley it's worth noting that you don't need `begin` keyword if you want to rescue all code of method.

Comment: You mean implicit exception blocks (like when defining a method) or something else?

Comment: @LeviStanley yes, I mean implicit exception blocks.

Comment: @MarekLipka I added a link to another question; it includes a lot more information including mention of implicit exception blocks.