# How do I get my rails app to work around errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, mechanize

My rails app is a web scraper using Mechanize / Nokogiri. Due to problems with KBB.com and their cookies I have to clear my cookie jar in my app every time I issue a new get request to their server.

```
agent.cookie_jar.clear!
```

However, while my app is scraping data, occasionally it hits a KBB.cpm page with an automatic redirect! This causes an error:

```
Mechanize::ResponseCodeError: 500 => Net::HTTPInternalServerError for http://www.kbb.com/toyota/prius/2002-toyota-prius/sedan-4d/options/?vehicleid=4843&intent=buy-used -- unhandled response
```

This causes my rails app to crash because I can't clear the cookie jar before it redirects. Instead, what I would like for my app to do is recognize that it could hit an error and if it does to use a different process. Something like:

```
if there_is_an_error
  # alternative process for redirect
else
  # business as usual
end
```

here's my code:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.cookie_jar.clear!
page = agent.get(url)
agent.cookie_jar.clear!
page.link_with(:text => "Choose this style").click
agent.cookie_jar.clear!
agent.page.link_with(:text => "Choose price type").click
agent.cookie_jar.clear!
agent.page.links_with(:text => "Get used car price")[2].click
url = agent.page.uri.to_s.sub('retail', 'private-party')
agent.cookie_jar.clear!
agent.get(url)
@kbb_value = agent.page.at('.selected .value').text.delete('$')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_exceptions.htm on handling exceptions. There is also a stack overflow post about this: [Begin, Rescue and Ensure in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191632/begin-rescue-and-ensure-in-ruby) . You could fix your problem by setting a flag in the exception handling block, then checking for that flag later on in your code to find out if an exception occurred, and this should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can just rescue the Mechanize::ResponseCodeError exception and do your alternative process for redirect inside that block