# Suppress an error when saving a record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am saving data to a table.

```
Question
  title:string
  author_id:integer
  description:text
  upvotes:integer
```

If a "question.upvotes" value is 1000000000000000000000, it will cause an error since it can't be saved to the "integer" type column.

**How can I suppress this error? I want my program to continue running, even though the record failed to save.**

I tried this, but it doesn't suppress the error:

```
... some code

if my_question.save
end

some more code...
```

Comment: What error does it cause? What do you see when it fails to update?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation for `save`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save)?

Comment: @NielsAbildgaard this is likely a general Ruby question dealing with try / catch syntax, not specific to the active record .save method

Comment: error is `PG::NumericValueOutOfRange: ERROR:  value "1000000000000" is out of range for type integer`

Comment: Or you could just test the value to see if it won't save. That said, silently failing to meet the user expectation and perhaps an other programmer's is a not a good general design principle.

Comment: @Donny P the error does not arise when saving. It happens before that: when you try to pass a non-integer number (too large) as an argument to a function which takes an integer. Validation before trying to save is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... some code

begin
  if my_question.save
    ...
  end
rescue
  # error handling
end

some more code ...
```

You receive `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NumericValueOutOfRange: ERROR:  integer out of range` error. If you want to catch exactly this error, you can specify this directly:

```
rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
```

also you can add a block which will be always executed with

```
ensure
```

[You can find more about exceptions handling here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2191632/644810) / [And see exceptions hierarchy here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Exception.html)

Comment: In Rails 5.2 `ActiveModel::RangeError` is raised instead. Man this makes things rescue logic brittle.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps just pin that value to the biggest possible value? Add something like this to your `Question` model:

```
# app/models/question.rb
UPVOTE_MAX_VALUE = 2_147_483_647          # integer max value in postgresql
before_validation :check_upvote_max_size

private
def check_upvotes_max_size
  self.upvotes = UPVOTE_MAX_VALUE         if upvotes > UPVOTE_MAX_VALUE
end
```