# Begin.. Rescue.. Rescue.. Ensure only for errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Have a quick question on Begin, Rescue, Ensure.  Take the following code for example:

```
begin
  user = User.new

  # Do stuff with User

  user.save if user.valid?

  # Do other stuff here...

  # ## Error happens here after user has already been saved. ##

  render text: "Success", status: :ok
rescue MyExceptions::MySpecialError => e
  # Do something special here for an error
  # Output errors the user has power to fix themselves
  render text: "You messed up!", status: :bad_request
rescue => e
  # Do something special here for an error the user can't fix
  render text: "Internal Error! See support!", status: :unprocessed_entity
ensure
  # If user was created, destroy them
  user.destroy
end
```

Ensure runs regardless if an error happened or not.  Is there a way to only run the user.destroy (or the ensure) only if an error has happened?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just put the `user.destroy` into `rescue` block. Sidenote: since it's Rails you might want use the `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`

Comment: So, I have to place user.destroy in both rescue blocks?  Trying to keep it DRY a bit.  I went ahead and used transactions for this case, but just an explanation for references purposes...

Comment: same [HEAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191632/begin-rescue-and-ensure-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

The code in the `ensure` will be executed no matter if there is an error or not, and this is practically the benefit of using it.

In your specific case, you can move the `user.destroy` inside the `rescue`, and it will run only if an error occurs.