# Missing required keys rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a form for task in my app.App has two entities:

- Project `belongs_to` User
- Task `belongs_to` Project

But I get this error in my view when I'm trying to create this (pretty basic) form

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"tasks"} missing required keys: [:project_id]
```

Here is a part of my view with this form

```
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus col-xs-1 left_plus" ></div>
        <div class="col-xs-10" >
        <%= form_for [@project, @task],url: project_tasks_path do |f| %>
          <%= f.input :body,class: 'form-control' %>
          <%= f.submit 'Add task', class: 'btn' %>
        <% end %>
```

And here is the project controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!


  def index
    @projects = current_user.projects unless current_user.nil?
    @task = Task.find_by(params[:project_id])
  end

  def show
    @task = @project.tasks.build
  end

  def new
    @project = current_user.projects.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @project = current_user.projects.create(project_params)

    if @project.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @project.update(project_params)
      redirect_to @project
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    redirect_to projects_path
  end

  private

  def load_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name, :user_id)
  end

end
```

And the tasks controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @tasks = Task.where(project_id: project_id)
  end

  def show
    project = Project.find_by(id: params[:project_id])
    @task = Task.new(project: project)
  end

  def new
    project = Project.find_by(id: params[:project_id])
    @task = Task.new(project: project)
  end


  def edit
    project = Project.find_by(id: params[:project_id])
    @task = Task.new(project: project)
  end

  def references
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.valid?
        format.html { redirect_to root_url }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :home_url }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.find_by(id: params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.create(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.valid?
        format.html { redirect_to root_url }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :home_url }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_url }
        format.json { render :home_url, status: :ok, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :root_url }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:deadline, :body, :project_id)
    end
end
```

The routes file:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'projects#index'

  resources :projects do
    resources :tasks
  end
```

And my routes:

```
projects#index
                   project_tasks GET      /projects/:project_id/tasks(.:format)          tasks#index
                                 POST     /projects/:project_id/tasks(.:format)          tasks#create
                new_project_task GET      /projects/:project_id/tasks/new(.:format)      tasks#new
               edit_project_task GET      /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id/edit(.:format) tasks#edit
                    project_task GET      /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#show
                                 PATCH    /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
                                 PUT      /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
                                 DELETE   /projects/:project_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#destroy
                        projects GET      /projects(.:format)                            projects#index
                                 POST     /projects(.:format)                            projects#create
                     new_project GET      /projects/new(.:format)                        projects#new
                    edit_project GET      /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                   projects#edit
                         project GET      /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#show
                                 PATCH    /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#update
                                 PUT      /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#update
                                 DELETE   /projects/:id(.:format)                        projects#destroy
```

Can somebody please help me to clarify where is the problem and what is the problem?

Comment: what's the name of the view where you put your form_for helper? can you pls tell us in which folder did you put it as well?

Comment: @davideghz index.html.erb (placed in views/projects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `TasksController#index` action. What is `project_id` there? For accessing a project's tasks, the project needs to exist in the first place. And not just that. To access any CRUD action on tasks, a project has to exist first.

Modify your TasksController as

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @tasks = @project.tasks
  end

  def show
    #makes use of set_task
  end

  def new
    @task = @project.tasks.new
  end


  def edit
  end

  def references
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.valid?
        format.html { redirect_to root_url }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :home_url }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @task = @project.tasks.create(task_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.valid?
        format.html { redirect_to root_url }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :home_url }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_url }
        format.json { render :home_url, status: :ok, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :root_url }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  def set_project
    @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:project_id]
  end

  def set_task
    @task = @project.tasks.find(params[:id])
  end

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:deadline, :body, :project_id)
  end
end
```

Since we have defined a `before_action` set_project, `@project` will be available to all methods. Note that `set_project`finds the project from the projects created by the current user.

In the ProjectsController#index, you won't actually get a value for `params[:project_id]`. Modify your index action to

```
def index
@projects = current_user.projects unless current_user.nil?
end
```

And I don't understand your `show` method. The `build` method is actually used to create a in-memory representation of an object. The `show` method of projects_controller can be used to display the project along with its tasks. If this is what you need, change you `show` action in `ProjectsController` to

```
def show
  #@project is available from load_project
  @tasks = @project.tasks
end
```

You could also modify your `load_project` project as

```
def load_project
  begin
    @project = Project.find(params[:id]) #raises an exception if project not found        
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to projects_path
  end
end
```

To know more about rescuing exceptions, see [Begin, Rescue and Ensure in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191632/begin-rescue-and-ensure-in-ruby)

For more, see http://blog.8thcolor.com/en/2011/08/nested-resources-with-independent-views-in-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: I've modified the controller - but the error is still the same

Comment: What url are trying to access? Remember you need a project id to be passed in the url. Url should be something like `http://localhost:3000/projects/3/tasks`

Comment: I'm trying to get  
 localhost:3000/projects/36 - but still getting this error

Comment: Why do you need @task in projects/index.html.erb? For displaying a form in projects/index.html.erb? The issue is with `params[:project_id]`. You won't get that from the `params` hash in the `index` action

Comment: So what should I do with this situation?

Comment: Tell me why you need `@task` in the index action. It'll help me resolve the issue.

Comment: Well,actually this may be some shitty decision from me, but I just want to view my projects' tasks here.Should I move this variables to another action?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Have a look at it. I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Well I've made all of your updates and now the error is - undefined method `tasks' for nil:NilClass  NoMethodError in ProjectsController#index

Comment: It just means you're searching for a non-existent project. So, `@project` is nil. And you can't call the `tasks` method on a nil object.

Comment: I have updated my answer to rescue an exception(when a project doesn't exist). I hope everything works now.

Comment: 1 minute please there is some syntax error in this exception, I'll try to figure this

Comment: Thats because you there's no `@projects` variable available to you from show action. And in fact, in the show page, you would only want to display a particular project. So, replace the loop with and try to display the attributes of `@project` and not `@projects`. You can also create a new loop to display all the tasks like `<% @tasks.each do |t| %>... <% end %>`

Comment: The humour is that the project#index page is the root page of the app.I'll create some another root page or set the devise page to root and I think the issue will be solved, TY

Comment: I have modified the code to redirect to the projects_path. You don't have to create a new root page.

Comment: And in this case I still don't have the @projects in my index or show actions)

Comment: Updated my code for index action of `ProjectsController`. Why do you need `@task` in index action anyway?

Comment: I don't know,as I said - maybe it was just a shitty solution) well now there is another error on the view - <%= form_for [@project, @task] do |f| %> in views/projects/index.html.erb  has `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` so I guess the @project  wasn't loaded into this action

Comment: Remove the form from index action, because we don't have access to the `@project` or `@task` variable in the index action. Maybe you can move it to the show action of `ProjectsController`. Add `@task = @project.tasks.new` in show action and you can use the form template in `projects/show.html.erb`

Comment: hm, will I be able to set projects/show.html.erb as a root page? or it would be better to set up a redirect to this page?

Comment: I think `projects_path`(index) should be the root path. In the index page, for every project displayed, include a link to the show page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the url for submitting the form. If you check your `rake routes` you'd see that all your task routes would be nested under projects, therefore in passing the url option, you should have something like:

```
   <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus col-xs-1 left_plus" ></div>
    <div class="col-xs-10" >
    <%= form_for [@project, @task],url: project_tasks_path(@project) do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :body,class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= f.submit 'Add task', class: 'btn' %>
    <% end %>
```

or even better, I think you should be able to do that without passing the url option:

```
    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus col-xs-1 left_plus" ></div>
     <div class="col-xs-10" >
     <%= form_for [@project, @task] do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :body,class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= f.submit 'Add task', class: 'btn' %>
    <% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

```
def index
  project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @projects = ProjectsViewPresenter.new(project)
end

# presenters/projects_view_presenter.rb
class ProjectsViewPresenter
  attr_reader :project
  def initialize(project)
    @project = project
  end

  def tasks
   @tasks ||= project.tasks
  end

  def task
   @task ||= tasks.new
  end
end
```

Your form_for would now be like this:

```
   <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus col-xs-1 left_plus" ></div>
    <div class="col-xs-10" >
    <%= form_for [@project.project, @project.task] do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :body,class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= f.submit 'Add task', class: 'btn' %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: I've tried to add (@project) and (project) to my url option - but now I'm getting an error undefined method to_key' for #<Task::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe91cca06e0> Did you mean? to_query to_set to_ary` –

Comment: No, you have instantiate the @project as an instance variable, that is in your new action, you should change from `project` to `@project` or use a Facade object to manage your view objects.

Comment: I've tried project_tasks_path(@project) , but now I get almost the same error  `No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"tasks", :project_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:project_id]
`

Comment: Wait, are you using your new action or index action?

Comment: I'm using an index action

Comment: he's using index action of projects_controller to show the form.. the problem is in how @task is declared ...

Comment: You're instantiating the `@tasks`, which would be a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, I believe you want to use the `@tasks`, you'd need a reference to `@task` as well, which would be `@task = @tasks.new`, you could use a presenter or facade to not clutter your actions with too many instance variables

Comment: Intrinsically, that means you'd need a reference to these 3 instance variables in your action: `@project, @tasks, @task`

Comment: @oreoluwa I've added `@task = @tasks.new` to my tasks controller and updated the view to look like `form_for [@project, @tasks, @task]` but it still doesn't work(

Comment: nope, your form_for should be `form_for [@project, @task]`

Comment: @oreoluwa I've also tried to reference all 3 variables in my question - and it still doesn't work

Comment: @oreoluwa can you please update your answer with your varian of tasks controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120375/discussion-between-mikhah-and-oreoluwa).

Answer (score 0):

If the form to create a new task is in projects/index.html.erb you should make a @task variable available to the view; try to change the index action as follow:

```
def index
  @projects = current_user.projects unless current_user.nil?
  @task = Task.new
end
```

Comment: I've made some changes that @oreoluwa proposed - index action of tasks controller -   def index
    @tasks = Task.where(project_id: project_id)
    @task = @tasks.new
    @project = Project.find_by(id: params[:project_id])
  end  but the code still doesn't work ,now with next error -   error undefined method `tasks_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe91c9f8938>:0x007fe91c922db0> 
Did you mean? asset_path

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.. anyway, it looks like @oreoluwa is helping you in chat. Let us know if you get your code to work :)

Comment: I didn't made those downwotes and oreoluwa is silent