# csv writer to stdout throws error in with block

Tags: python, csv, stdout

How to force `csv.writer()` to accept stdout inside with block?

I this works ok:

```
with (open(output, "w")) if output != 'stdout' else stdout as file:
```

this is also fine:

```
file = csv.writer(open(output, "w") if output != 'stdout' else stdout)
```

but when I try this:

```
with csv.writer(open(output, "w") if output != 'stdout' else stdout) as file:
```

I get `AttributeError: __exit__`

How to make this with block work please? I am looking for solution like [ruby solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738098/write-csv-to-stdout-or-filename) but for python.

Comment: `csv.writer` doesn't have to close the handle on exit. Hence no `__exit__` method, and it makes no sense to put `csv.writer` in a `with` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `csv.writer` doesn't have to close the handle on exit. Hence no `__exit__` method, and it makes no sense to put `csv.writer` in a `with` statement.
- With my python version, your original `with open` code doesn't work, I get a `AttributeError: __exit__`
- And even if it worked (seems to work on Python 3.6 as the other answer has tested it), it closes `stdout`. Not what you want.

I've created a "fake" file object with `__enter__` and `__exit__` (does nothing) methods. this object complies with the `with` constraints.

```
import csv,sys

output="stdout"
class FakeStdout:
    def write(self,data):
        sys.stdout.write(data)
    def __exit__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        pass
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

with (open(output, "w") if output != 'stdout' else FakeStdout()) as file:
    cw = csv.writer(file)
    cw.writerow([1,2,3])

print("lll")
```

This code prints:

```
1,2,3
lll
```

it works with standard output and doesn't close it when exiting

Answer (score 3):

Refactored slightly:

```
import csv
from sys import stdout

#output = "temp.txt"
output = "stdout"

with (open(output, "w") if output != 'stdout' else stdout) as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["A","B","C"])
```

works on Python 3.6, at least.

But... **this will close stdout after the with block completes.**

For example:

```
with (open(output, "w") if output != 'stdout' else stdout) as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["A","B","C"])

print("AFTER")  # Raises "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."
```

---

I think the best approach is just to handle the file closing directly.  You do lose the benefit of the context manager auto-closing the file on exceptions, but without doing some additional work creating a pseduo-stdout that doesn't actually close on `__exit__`, your best bet might be:

```
import csv
from sys import stdout

#output = "temp.txt"
output = "stdout"

file = (open(output, "w") if output != 'stdout' else stdout)

writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(["A","B","C"])

if output != "stdout": file.close()

print("AFTER")
```

Comment: of course... I am coding for 12 hours now... should get some break :D Thanks!

Comment: @PapeK24 See my edit, the side effect of the with block closing stdout may not be what you want.

Comment: it doesnt work in python 3.4. Cannot find `__exit__` on `stdout`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't like it even when it works.  I'm editing it.

Comment: @jedwards good point on closing the stdout. I was expecting that too and got `AttributeError` instead because running previous version of python.

Comment: with a custom object, see my answer

Comment: @PapeK24 I edited my answer to do it "manually", and the "pseudo-stdout" that I described is perfectly encapsulated in Jean-Francois' answer -- he has more patience than I do :)

Comment: I think that's a pretty neat question. Why depriving from the nice `with` construct because of lame stdout?

Comment: I agree -- I hope @PapeK24 will shift the check mark.  Your answer is more pythonic and more robust.

Comment: @jedwards  @Jean-François Fabre Is it maybe possible to inherit `FakeStdout` from clasic one and only redefine `__exit__` ?

Comment: inherit from a class, yes, from an instance? more difficult :) what could be possible would be to redefine `__exit__` on `stdout` itself.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thats true... yeah not gonna redefine original one, that may cause issues at some point. Thanks for help.