# How to rescue null in C#?

Tags: c#, null, rescue

I wonder if there is a way to `rescue null` as we do `rescue nil` in Ruby?

I know `rescue nil` and tertiary aren't good practice, but I'm still a bit old school.

Thanks

Comment: Do you just mean an empty `catch` block?

Comment: Can you give an example of exactly what it is you want to do?

Comment: "as we do rescue nil in Ruby?" since not all of the C# programmers here automatically know Ruby, it would be good if you could describe what "rescue" actually does there. A description would help us to find a proper equivalent if it exists

Comment: @MongZhu, should we add tag `ruby` to question? Or would c# tag annoy ruby experts as much as ruby in question us?

Comment: @Sinatr :D I had the same thought. But I hesitated to add the tag. Without a proper description is search for a possible equivalent is hopeless, unless someone comes along who knows both languages. Linh if you want to speed up things provide a description

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191632/begin-rescue-and-ensure-in-ruby/2192010) looks promising